# I am trying these commands but show error in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, php

i am trying these commands listed below but its gives me error again and again. i am also using putty with public key.

error is:

> Could not open input file:

commands is:

1. php bin/magento cache:flush
2. php bin/magento cache:clean

Comment: Are you actually talking about a `Magento 1.9` store? Because the commands you're trying to run are for `Magento 2.x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your question info and tags you used, it seems you are `using Magento ver 1.9` and the commands you are trying to execute doesn't exist for Magento 1.9.x

If you are asking for Magento 2.x

**To flush Cache Using Command Line**

you can use `sudo` so the commands will become

> sudo php bin/magento cache:flush

**View cache status Using Command Line**

> php bin/magento cache:status

whenever commands needs to read/write a folder it needs proper permission either set correct permission as per user or use `sudo` ( not suggested )